# Difference between custom memory allocators and pools

Tags: c, memory, memory-management

As far as I can understand, a memory pool is essentially a mechanism that allocates a big chunk of memory and then provides chunks of memory by increasing the pointers to the previously allocated.

Custom allocators like `tcmalloc` are essentially better versions of `malloc` and `free` that overwrite these functions, but don't necessarily have any pool of memory which means that some applications could benefit from a custom memory allocator and a memory pool *at the same time*.

However, I was told this is wrong. Is that so?

Comment: What were you told was wrong?  That 'a memory pool … allocates a big chunk of memory and then provides chunks of memory by increasing the pointers', or that 'custom allocators like `tcmalloc` are essentially better versions of `malloc`', or that 'custom allocators like `tcmalloc` don't necessarily have any pool of memory', or that 'some applications could benefit from a custom memory allocator and a memory pool at the same time' — or any combination of these?

Comment: Essentially I was told that the concepts could actually not be separated from each other, but as far as I can see from your answer, this ain't true, right?

Comment: My previous comment cannot be construed as an answer; it asks you to disambiguate your question — to establish what you were told was wrong. I have to confess that I'm not sure what you mean by memory pool; most `malloc()` implementation allocate space out of a pool of memory that they've established. The 'increasing pointers' commentary often applies to `malloc`  `tcmalloc` is Google's Thread Caching Malloc; it is designed for minimal contention in threaded programs; otherwise, it is a `malloc()` replacement. Maybe I'd have a view if I knew how a 'memory pool' is different from `malloc`.